# SVN and SSL handshake failure

Tags: apache, svn, ssl, openssl

I'd like to access my SVN server with the below SVN command:

```
svn info https://local.myserver.ne.jp:49158/svn/myproject --username guest --password xxxxx --no-auth-cache  -rHEAD
```

The command returns :

```
SSL handshake failed: SSL error: A TLS warning alert has been received.
```

I have generated a new certificate with "local.myserver.ne.jp" as CN with :

```
openssl req -new > new.ssl.csr

openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -out new.cert.key
openssl x509 -in new.ssl.csr -out new.cert.cert -req -signkey new.cert.key -days NNN

cp new.cert.cert /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
cp new.cert.key /etc/ssl/certs/server.key
```

I've updated my ssl.conf with these 2 files (I've checked certificate's CN with browser, it was the new one).

I retried the svn command , but I get the same error message

```
SSL handshake failed: SSL error: A TLS warning alert has been received.
```

Does someone know how to fix it ?

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the "ServerName" value in my httpd.conf file, and it works now !

ServerName 127.0.0.1:80　->  ServerName local.myserver.ne.jp

Thank you